# When using Laravel and Ardent, and when trying to use good testing practice, how would I make this work?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mocking, ardent

I'm using Laravel 4 and I followed JeffreyWay's testing book. Right now I'm working on testing my controllers. My specific question is in regards to line 69 of this: http://paste.laravel.com/v2B

Since I obviously can't do this, what do I need to do? I've tried also using

```
$user = $this->user;
```

but this didn't work. I'm very much new to unit testing, so I'm still trying to figure things out. Does anyone have suggestions of what I need to do?

Comment: See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115979/when-you-should-and-should-not-use-the-new-keyword

Answer (score 0):

I'm also very new to Laravel 4 AND testing. If you are testing creating a user, you could look into the Input::replace() method. You'll basically supply an array of data and then test it. Net Tuts has a pretty extensive tutorial on testing controllers.

[Testing Laravel Controllers](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-laravel-controllers/)